# Is there a SAX Parser for Delphi and Free Pascal?

Tags: xml, delphi, parsing, sax, freepascal

Besides MSXML and [SAX for Pascal](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxforpascal/), can you recommend a SAX parser for Delphi? It would be great if it could be used in cross-platform applications with Free Pascal.

Comment: pull-parser is not SAX-parser but might have all its benefits as well. See MS XMLLite stats at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QcFVwh3fFfaDyRmv2b-n4Rq4_u5p42UfNbR_FZgZizY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open-source [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) engine supports SAX, and has a [Pascal binding](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libxml2-pas/) available.

Comment: Free Pascal has an additional binding.

Answer (score 4):

[OXML](http://www.kluug.net/oxml.php) also provides support for SAX and outperforms most other parsers (yes even libxml2).

Comment: But the guy does not answers mails. So, it is not truly Opensource and it is not reliably commercial. While sounds very promising it looks like a dead-end lock-in...

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [DIXml](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/xml/index).

Answer (score 2):

Euh, the SAX xml parser that comes with FPC ?  See the [fcl-xml package](http://wiki.freepascal.org/fcl-xml).

Afaik the recent activity on this package has made it largely Delphi compatible even.